# Are there any Arduino libraries that allow you to upload data directly to PostgreSQL?

Tags: arduino-ide

Are there any Arduino libraries that allow you to upload data directly to PostgreSQL?

I have been turning the internet upside down to answer this question but most of the information is several years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution to this question that I could find is a GitHub repository that hasn't been touched in several years called, SimplePgSQL. Feel free to add a better answer if you are able to find something more current. More current information would be useful!

https://github.com/ethanak/SimplePgSQL

Comment: Looks like the other alternative is to use a Raspberry Pi to easily upload sensor data to a Postgresql database.